# Clojure: First Function and Tick Marks

Tags: clojure

```
(ns main.core)

(defn andexp [& resty]
  (println "here is resty:" resty)
  (first (resty))
)
```

I am very new to Clojure coming from a Java and C background
In the repl, the input has to be in this format:

```
(andexp '(John is a beginner so have mercy))
```

I **need** to include the tick mark ('). I want my program to print out "John."

Comment: @cfrick I accidently deleted your comment. But I still want to store the rest of the variable 'u are a noob' into someting. like a variable

Comment: No worries - _i_ deleted it, as i wrote an answer from it (there where other things wrong)

Answer (score 2):

There are two things happening here:

You are using `& resty` to destructure for a list of all the arguments; that is why you see the output of `((John ...))` (note the double `(())`.

Next you are *calling* `resty`, when you write `(resty)`, which results in an error (remember, parens in clojure are always meaningful and not just for groupting things togehter etc. like in curly braces languages).

So this will do what you want:

```clj
repl=> (defn andexp [resty]
         (println "here is resty:" resty)
         (first resty))
#'repl/andexp
repl=> (andexp '(a b c))
here is resty: (a b c)
a
```

If you really want to destructure (like stated in the comments), you have to put your arguments into another pair of `[]` to destructure on the passed in list.  E.g.

```clj
repl=> (defn andexp [[f & resty]]
         (println "here is f and resty:" f resty)
         (first resty))
#'repl/andexp
repl=> (andexp '(a b c))
here is f and resty: a (b c)
b
```

More infos about
[destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring)

Comment: what does  #_=> mean?

Comment: Thank you! Where could I look up destructuring? Unless you could explain how it works? (Basically, I'd like to know WHY something works for future reference)

Comment: @educationalmonkey97 Here's a guide to destructuring in clojure: https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring

Comment: @educationalmonkey97 Those are the line break characters of my repl.  I realize, that this is confusing to a beginner and will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you write it like so:

```
(defn andexp
  [& resty]
  (println "here is resty:" resty)
  (first resty))
```

you will get a result:

```
(andexp '(John is a beginner so have mercy))  #=>

    here is resty: ((John is a beginner so have mercy))
    (John is a beginner so have mercy)
```

but you probably wanted something more like this:

```
(defn andexp
  [& resty]
  (println "here is resty:" resty)
  (first resty))

(println :result (andexp  1 2 3 4) )  ; no wrapping parens
```

with result:

```
here is resty: (1 2 3 4)
:result 1
```

Another option:

```
(defn andexp
  [& resty]
  (println "here is resty:" resty)
  (first (first resty))) ; or `ffirst`

(println :result (andexp [1 2 3 4]) )
```

with result:

```
here is resty: ([1 2 3 4])
:result 1
```

---

It may help to clarify the answer if you add more info about the use-case or goal.

---

For background, please see the documentation listed here:

https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation

Comment: With due respect, I want the output "John". Not sure how this is related

Comment: my input has to be "(andexp '(John is a beginner so have mercy))" in the repl. that's it